# Path completion for assets folder in Visual Studio Code project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

VS Code (I'm using Insiders 1.38) works perfectly with path intellisense for imports in a Typescript file such as 
`import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';` as typing `../` immediately shows me `shared` and its siblings.

However I'm trying to find a way — which used to work at some point — of getting intellisense for paths within my project, like from my assets folder so I can do

```
<img src="/assets/images/mobile/touchid.jpg">
```

When I type the `/` I get the root of my VS Code project:

[image]

If I continue and type the correct root path `/assets/` I get:

[image]

Where `app-heroheader` is a simple Angular component in my project.

I have tried the [Path Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) and [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) extensions and get the same result.

Is there no way for me to get path suggestions for `/assets/` or `assets/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path-Intellisense - You can do it with `assets/`, not `/assets/` though, at least that I've been able to figure out.

In your workspace settings.json you can add the following custom mapping:

```
{
    "path-intellisense.mappings": {
        "assets": "${workspaceRoot}/src/assets",
    }
}
```

Then when you start typing `assets/`you'll get the directory.

Example:

[image]

Comment: That's what I thought, but I still get the bogus suggestion of my component instead of the rest of the path after `assets/`

Comment: Is it possible you have some other extension that's causing the issue? I JUST did a clean install of Insiders 1.38 and ONLY installed path-intellisense extension and it is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, it works now.  It seems the Angular Component Extension was what broke it.

Comment: If you don't have it already, the Angular Language Service extension is a good alternative to Angular Component Extension.

Comment: With this solution intellisense works and images are shown correctly but it does not solve "follow link" (ctrl+click) functionality. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: I had more luck with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete It seems to have a bit more flexible mappings.